# Java caching SSL failures - can I flush these somehow

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to test my SSL implementation in unit tests and have one scenario I can't quite understand.

When I connect to a host once and fail, every following connection will fail also, even if it has the correct certificates. I'm assuming somewhere along the way I'd have to flush a cache.

Here is my code, server and client are running locally. I use one jks-File for both trustStore and keyStore. The error occurrs no matter what the initial error was, I'll always get the first error the next time.

If I don't perform the first request the second one works.

If you're wondering what the use case is here, we have some local servers that use https certificates from an internal PKI, when someone misconfigures a server or a certificate, we'd like to be able to change them obviously, without shutting down the whole VM.

```
    //attempt a connection without certificates, will fail
    try (final InputStream stream = new URL("https://localhost:" + port).openStream()){
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(stream, Charset.defaultCharset()));
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed to load: " + StackTraceUtil.getStackTrace(e));
    }

    //copies the jks file to a temporary location
    final File jksFile = copyJKSFile();

    //ignore host names, running locally, won't use this in production
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, sslSession) -> hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost"));

    //set the system properties
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", jksFile.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", jksFile.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password);

    //this should work now
    try (final InputStream stream = new URL("https://localhost:" + port).openStream()){
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(stream, Charset.defaultCharset()));
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed to load: " + StackTraceUtil.getStackTrace(e));
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found a solution and I thought I'd share it in case someone else would have this problem at some point.

The class `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` uses a `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` to load the Key- and TrustStore, which uses a `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext` internally. When you don't overwrite anything, it uses the default implementation, which loads the files and can't be reset once loaded.

So what I did was not to use the default implementation, but to set my own `SSLContext`, when I knew the files would change.

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

If you want to use older versions of TLS, the full list should be [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I might need that someday :)