# HttpUrlConnection.getOutputStream causes "Handshake message sequence violation, 11" exception when same connection was opened 2nd time

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, handshake

I am creating new HttpUrlConnection, enabling output, setting request method and getting request output stream.
When I repeat it 2nd time, there is an `SSLProtocolException` thrown with error `Handshake message sequence violation, 11`

Here is an example code that causes the issue for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("execute1");
        execute();
        System.out.println("execute2");
        execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void execute() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("https://payments.sandbox.braintree-api.com/graphql");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.getOutputStream();
}
```

I have enabled SSL handshake debug via following options:

```
 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

Below is what I see in the stdout. I notice this curious part, right before "execute2":

```
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
```

I wonder if this is the cause of the issue? What's the proper way to dispose of this "cached client session"?

If not, here's all the output (I've removed specific URL and certificate details). Stack trace at the very bottom:

```
execute1
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Inaccessible trust store: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\security\jssecacerts
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is: jks
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Tue Jun 04 14:44:01 MSK 2019
Reload the trust store
Reload trust certs
Reloaded 106 trust certs
adding as trusted cert:
< listing a bunch of certs here>

keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
main, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=<my server URL>) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=<my server URL>)
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1563997941 bytes = { <...> }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=<...>]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 236
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 74
check handshake state: server_hello[2]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 2141312119 bytes = { <...> }
Session ID:  {<...>}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
update handshake state: server_hello[2]
upcoming handshake states: server certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: server_key_exchange[12](optional)
upcoming handshake states: certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4205
check handshake state: certificate[11]
update handshake state: certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: server_key_exchange[12](optional)
upcoming handshake states: certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [ <certificate chain here> ]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[ <trusted certificate details> ]
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 333
check handshake state: server_key_exchange[12]
update handshake state: server_key_exchange[12]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: <...>
  public y coord: <...>
  parameters: <...>
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
check handshake state: server_hello_done[14]
update handshake state: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { <...> }
update handshake state: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
<...>
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
<...>
Server Nonce:
<...>
Master Secret:
<...>
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
<...>
Server write key:
<...>
Client write IV:
<...>
Server write IV:
<...>
update handshake state: change_cipher_spec
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { <...> }
***
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
update handshake state: change_cipher_spec
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
check handshake state: finished[20]
update handshake state: finished[20]
*** Finished
verify_data:  { <...> }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
execute2
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
main, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=<...>) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=<...>)
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% Client cached [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
%% Try resuming [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256] from port 52832
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1563997941 bytes = { <...> }
Session ID:  {<...>}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=<...>]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 74
check handshake state: server_hello[2]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1520426416 bytes = { <...> }
Session ID:  {<...>}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
<...>
Server Nonce:
<...>
Master Secret:
<...>
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
<...>
Server write key:
<...>
Client write IV:
<...>
Server write IV:
<...>
%% Server resumed [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
update handshake state: server_hello[2]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4205
check handshake state: certificate[11]
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 11
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 11
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeStateManager.check(HandshakeStateManager.java:362)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:196)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
    at Main.execute(Main.java:51)
    at Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

I would also like to note that this happens on my workplace network only, that does HTTPS traffic inspection (and custom certification authority is installed on my workstation and JRE)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I have figured out how to remedy this. Following answer on a related question has helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763227/1384013

I have added the code from that answer at the beginning of the "execute" method in my sample code:

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

And the exception is gone. But this doesn't look like a proper solution, since those sockets are supposed to be reusable...

Update: I found another solution. I can invalidate SSL sessions for a specific host, which looks a bit less blunt:

```
static void invalidateSslSessions(String forHost){
    try {
        SSLSessionContext sc = SSLContext.getDefault().getClientSessionContext();
        while (sc.getIds().hasMoreElements()) {
            byte[] sessionId = sc.getIds().nextElement();
            SSLSession session = sc.getSession(sessionId);
            if (session.getPeerHost().equals(forHost)){
                session.invalidate();
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOG.error("Could not validate SSL session for " + forHost);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I would call it after finishing work with URLConnection:

```
invalidateSslSessions(url.getHost());
```

Although I still don't understand what causes the error, so there should be a better fix.